# Read a specific object from a CollectionGroup

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection within another (CollectionGroup) and now I want to read a specific object from it. Currently I'm trying as shown below, but I'm not getting any result:

```
db.collectionGroup("Objekte")
  .whereEqualTo("timestamp",key.toString())
  .get()
  .addOnSuccessListener { doc->
    for (document : doc) {
        if(document != null)
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
       } else{
            Log.d("TAG", "No such document")
       }
    }
}
```

[image]

TIMESTAMP LOGOUT:

**TIMESTAMP:1672216119769**

Comment: Can you `Log.d("TAG", "Timestamp: ${key.toString()}")` and share the output?

Comment: Added it to the post above

Comment: Have you tried to attach a Failure listener? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: I'm with Alex here: since collection group queries require a specific index and rules, be sure to catch errors and log them.